# Check if a tree is a min heap

Tags: tree, prolog, min-heap

How do I get a predicate in prolog to return a value?

I need to find a node of a tree and also check if its a min heap or not.
I'm guessing it goes something like this:-

```
getnode(tree(_, node, _), node).
```

My code so far is this

```
minheap(tree(L, Node, empty)) :-
    getnode(L, Val),
    Node =< Val,
    minheap(L).
minheap(tree(empty, Node, R)) :-
    getnode(R, Val),
    Node =< Val,
    minheap(R).

getnode(tree(_,n,_)  , n).
```

Input is of the type-

```
minheap(tree(empty,3,tree(tree(empty,8,empty),5,tree(empty,7,empty)))).
```

Output should be true.

Comment: What is the format of the `tree/3`? `tree(Left,Value,Right)`?

Comment: Yes,Thats correct

Comment: A tree rooted at a node is a min-heap iff the value of the node is less than (or at least not greater than) values of all (usually: both) child nodes _and_ all subtrees rooted at children are min-heaps, too. Is your code able to test _all_ children of a given node?

Comment: That is exactly where I am stuck. How do I get a extract a node from the input.
My logic might be incorrect at this point.

Comment: @JohnKeaton: also mind that **variables start with an uppercase**. So for `getnode/2` the `n` is **interpreted as a constant**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve this, you better define some utility predicates that make life simpler.

For instance predicate `lower/2`. `lower(Tree,Value)` that succeeds if either `Tree` is `empty`, or the value of the `Tree` is higher than `Value`. So you can implement this like:

```
lower(empty,_).
lower(tree(_,TreeValue,_),Value) :-
    TreeValue >= Value.
```

Next we define the predicate `minheap/1`. An `empty` tree is definitely a `minheap`. Furthermore a tree is a minheap if its children are lower and all the children are `minheap/1`s themselves, so:

```
minheap(empty).
minheap(tree(Left,Value,Right)) :-
    lower(Left,Value),
    lower(Right,Value),
    minheap(Left),
    minheap(Right).
```

and that's it. This is better than trying to do *all* the work in the `minheap/1` predicate since in that case you should handle *five* cases: `empty`, `tree(empty,val,empty)`, `tree(tree(..),val,empty)`, `tree(empty,val,tree(..))` and `tree(tree(..),val,tree(..))`. By using the `lower/2` helper predicate, we only have to handle two cases: `empty` and `tree/3`.

Comment: Thanks! 
I have no idea why I didn't think of that.

Comment: it is customary for the argument order to conform to a reading of `pred(A,B)` as "A is *pred* B".